# bind9 on container refuses queries from docker translated port

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, bind

I am running **bind9** DNS service from an Ubuntu container. UDP port 53 is published on host IP. Queries pointed directly at the container IP (from the host) receives an answer. However, queries pointed at the host IP return REFUSED status.

Command used to deploy container:

```
docker run -dit --net=new -p 192.168.37.152:53:53/udp --name 99 ubuntu
```

named configuration file in the container:

```
$ docker exec -it 99 cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        recursion yes;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        forwarders { 8.8.4.4; };
        listen-on { any; };
};
```

Container's IP address:

```
$ docker exec -it 99 ip a | grep inet\
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet 10.1.1.2/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global eth0
```

DiG output when pointed at container's IP:

```
$ dig @10.1.1.2 adobe.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> @10.1.1.2 adobe.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23978
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 095943567db30380010000005f24e59b887572779e0e50ab (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;adobe.com.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
adobe.com.              7       IN      A       192.147.130.204
adobe.com.              7       IN      A       193.104.215.58

;; Query time: 96 msec
;; SERVER: 10.1.1.2#53(10.1.1.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 01 03:46:35 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 98
```

DiG output when pointed at the host IP:

```
$ dig @192.168.37.152 adobe.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.37.152 adobe.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 38030
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: ba6997f5b02fd9a4010000005f24e5cee0bf9a6082cede1e (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;adobe.com.                     IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.37.152#53(192.168.37.152)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 01 03:47:26 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
```

Why does the query to host IP return a `REFUSED` response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly because `allow-recursion` is not set.  Try adding `allow-recursion { 192.168/16; };` to `named.conf.options`.

Comment: Turns out that bind9 allows recursion by default only on localhost and whatever interface it is connected to at the time of initialization [https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00269]